# jscript jquery выдает ошибку Failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Исходные данные:
На сервере есть `html` с забиваемыми исходными данными, по которым `jscript` c помощью `jquery` запрашивает с сайта инфу по ряду критериев через представленный API.

Данные запрашиваются по ID последовательно (со стороны API есть ограничение на кол-во запросов в секунду, но дело не в нём), например 1-10000 или 25000000-30000000.
Ответ получаемые в `json` парсится и выводится на ту же страницу.

**Исходный код html:**

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<title> API test</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="Test_App">
<div id="bodyMain">
        Filter Greater Than Last Battle: <input type="date" id="lastDate" />
        Search By ID (FROM): <input type="number" id="fromID" value="x"/>       Search By ID (TO): <input type="number" id="toID" value="xxxxx" /> <br>
        <br>
        WinRate From %: <input value="xx" type="number" id="winRateFrom" /> To <input value="xx" type="number" id="winRateTo" />
        <br> <!-- default item for winrate filter -->
        Exp:  <input type="number" id="_avg_xp_Default" value="xxx" />
        <br>
        Rating :  <input type="number" id="_global_rating_Default" value="xxx" />
        <br>
        battles :  <input type="number" id="_clan_battles_Default" value="xxx" />
        <br>
        Attack <input type="number" id="_str_A_battles_Default" value="xxx" />
        <br>
        Defence :  <input type="number" id="_str_D_battles_Default" value="xxx" />

        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="getFunction(true)" />
        <br>
        ID Received : <span id="pendingID">0</span> of <span id="toPendingID">0</span>
        &nbsp;<span id="alertMsg"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="exportExcel(event)" id="btnExport" value="Export as Excel File" />
        <table id="table_wrapp" style="width: 1200px;">
                <thead>
                                 <th>Account ID</th>
                                <th>Nickname</th>
                                <th>Last Battle</th>
                                <th>Created at</th>
                                <th>Global Rating</th>
                                <th>Average XP</th>
                                <th>Clan battles All </th>
                                <th>Stronghold Atack</th>
                                <th>Stronghold Defense</th>
                                <th>Win</th>
                                <th>Loses</th>
                                <th>Win %</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="jquery.excel.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="main.js?v2" defer="defer"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Исходный код скрипта:**

```
var accountFields = 'statistics.all.losses%2Cstatistics.all.wins%2Cstatistics.all.battles%2Cclan_id%2Cprivate.gold%2Caccount_id%2Clast_battle_time%2Ccreated_at%2Cglobal_rating%2Cstatistics.all.battle_avg_xp%2Cstatistics.clan.battles%2Cstatistics.globalmap_absolute.battles%2Cstatistics.globalmap_champion.battles%2Cstatistics.stronghold_defense.battles%2Cstatistics.stronghold_skirmish.battles%2Cnickname%2Cclient_language%2Cglobal_rating'         //Separted by , > "%2C" without quote
var applicationID = '********';
var reqPerMilSecond = 40 ;      //Request Per Milisecond. Will send request every 40 Milisec (1000 = 1sec)
var counter = 1;
var counter2 = 1;
var max = 100000000;
var html = []
function getFunction(flag){
        if(flag){
                $('#alertMsg').text('Please Wait')
                counter = parseInt($('#fromID').val());
                max = parseInt($('#toID').val());
                $('table>tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="5">Waiting For Response</td></tr>');
                $('#toPendingID').text(max);
                if(counter > max){
                        alert('To ID must be greater than From')
                        return;
                }
        }
        if($('#lastDate').val() == ''){
                alert('Please Input Date')
                return;
        }
        var query = getIds();
        main(query,function(data){
          var html = [];
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                var data = data.data
                var date = new Date(document.getElementById("lastDate").value);
                var winT = parseInt($('#winRateTo').val())
                var winF = parseInt($('#winRateFrom').val())
                var _avg_xp_D = parseInt($('#_avg_xp_Default').val())
                var _global_rating_D = parseInt($('#_global_rating_Default').val())
                var _clan_battles_D = parseInt($('#_clan_battles_Default').val())
                var _str_A_battles_D = parseInt($('#_str_A_battles_Default').val())
                var _str_D_battles_D = parseInt($('#_str_D_battles_Default').val())
                for(attr in data){
                        if(data[attr] && !data[attr]['clan_id']){       //This will check if there's a valid Player (data[attr])
                                var _date = new Date(parseInt(data[attr]['last_battle_time'])*1000);
                                var _battles = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['all']['battles']) || 0;
                                var _wins = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['all']['wins']) || 0;
                                var _winRate = (_wins/_battles)*100;
                                var _avg_xp = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['all']['battle_avg_xp']) || 0;
                                var _global_rating = parseInt(data[attr]['global_rating']) || 0;
                                var _clan_battles_all = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['clan']['battles']) || 0;
                                var _str_A_battles = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['stronghold_skirmish']['battles']) || 0;
                                var _str_D_battles = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['stronghold_defense']['battles']) || 0;
                                if(_date.getTime() >= date.getTime()){  //Filter player time
                                        if (winF<=_winRate && winT>=_winRate && _avg_xp>=_avg_xp_D && _global_rating>=_global_rating_D && _clan_battles_all>=_clan_battles_D && _str_A_battles>=_str_A_battles_D && _str_D_battles>=_str_D_battles_D)
                                        {
                                                                        var tempHTML = '<tr>';
                                                        var _lastBattle = getCurrDate(new Date(parseInt(data[attr]['last_battle_time']) * 1000));
 var tempHTML = '<tr>';
                                                        var _lastBattle = getCurrDate(new Date(parseInt(data[attr]['last_battle_time']) * 1000));
                                                                var _loses = parseInt(data[attr]['statistics']['all']['losses']) || 0;
                                                                var _created_at = getCurrDate(new Date(parseInt(data[attr]['created_at']) * 1000));
                                                                        var tempHTML = '<tr>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+data[attr]['account_id']+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+data[attr]['nickname']+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+_lastBattle+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+_created_at+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+_global_rating+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+_avg_xp+'</td>';
                                                                        tempHTML += '<td>'+_clan_battles_all+'</td>';
                                                           tempHTML += '<td>'+_str_A_battles+'</td>';
                                                              tempHTML += '<td>'+_str_D_battles+'</td>';
                                                             tempHTML += '<td>'+_wins+'</td>';
                                                            tempHTML += '<td>'+_loses+'</td>';
                                                           tempHTML += '<td>'+parseFloat(_winRate).toFixed(2)+'</td>';
                                                        tempHTML += '</tr>'
                                                        html.push(tempHTML);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
    if(tempHTML!=''){
      $('table>tbody').append(html.join());
    }
                counter2 += 100;
                if(counter2 >= max)
                        {
                $('#alertMsg').text('Done')
                        }
                $('#pendingID').text(counter2);
        },function()
                {
                })
  if(counter >= max){
  }else{
    setTimeout(function(){counter += 100; getFunction();}, reqPerMilSecond);
  }
}

function getIds(){
        var maxID = counter +100;
        var html2 = [];
        for(var x = counter;x<maxID;x++){
                html2.push(x)
        }
        return html2.join('%2C');
 }
        return html2.join('%2C');
}
main = function(query,callback,errorCallback){
        var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        var url = 'https://*****adress_syte*****/account/info/?application_id='+applicationID+'&';
                url += 'account_id='+query+'&';
                url += 'fields='+accountFields
        query = query;
        var dataSend = query
        $.ajax({
                url :url,
                data : { 'data': dataSend },
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType:contentType,
                method:'POST',
                success: function(datares){
                        datares = $.trim(datares);
                        var mydata = datares.replace(/'/g,'"');
                        callback(mydata);
                },error: function(xhr){
                }
        });
}

getCurrDate = function(d){
        var mon = (d.getMonth()+1)
        var day = ( d.getDate() )
        if(mon.toString().length == 1){
                mon = "0"+mon.toString();
        }
        if(day.toString().length == 1){
                day = "0"+day.toString();
        }
        var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
        var hr = d.getHours();
        var min = d.getMinutes();

        return strDate+' '+hr+':'+min;
}
```

Если запрашивать небольшой диапозон вроде 1-100000 и выбирать небольшую скорость запросов - всё ок.
А вот если запросить опрос диапозона ID в несколько миллионов например 
30,000,000-35,000,000, то в логах chrome через некоторое время вылезает ошибка (опытным путём установленно, что даже на низкой скорости опроса):

> jquery-3.2.1.js:9566 POST https://****адрес запроса****
>   net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

сама строка 9566:

> // Do send the request (this may raise an exception) xhr.send(
>   options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Я как программист нулевого уровня, подозреваю что это либо сам сервак не тянет (сокетов ему не хватает, хз, я незнаю), либо где-то в коде какая-то утечка памяти или что-то в этом духе.

При необходимости могу выложить timeline и профили Chrome.

Comment: Может хоть намекнёт кто, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Интересно, что если перенаправить вывод в файл, а не обновлять html то ошибок не возникает.

Comment: а, не... тоже самое ... хотя по субъективным ощущениям опрос-диапазон дольше держит

Comment: Может быть так что сервер не успевает принять все ответы? и как это можно отследить?

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого-то возникнет похожая проблема алгоритм поиска у меня был примерно такой:

1. Сделать альтернативный вывод (в лог/файл/базу) и сравнить скорость/время обработки.
2. Сделать трассировку запросов в браузере
3. В моём случае было видно, что запросы приходят, а запись запаздывает (точную причину я не стал выяснять)
4. Я перенастроил ряд параметров в /etc/sysctl.conf отвечающих за количество отрываемых сокетов, файлов, несколько таймаутов и т.п. - какой-то из этих параметров сработал. Ошибки в трассировке исчезли и всё ответы на запросы обрабатываются.